# Is it possible to abort drawing pixel of javascript/canvas method fill in adobe air?

Tags: javascript, canvas, air

I want to build a simple modelviewer. In fact that most 3D Engines for javascript/canvas out there are way too complex for my purpose I'd prefer building a small one on my own. By writing a z-buffer I'd like to check wether canvas API should draw a pixel over the existing image. At the moment I am using the method fill() to draw triangles. I do so because I'd like to avoid writing my own anti-aliasing stuff.  Are there any callbacks or is there any other way I can implement my check into the native script?

In fact that's going to be in Adobe AIR, are there any native ressources I could use to speed up(molehill/Stage3D WebGL? Dunno). Or are there any ways in combination of Flash? Actually I'd prefer Javascript but if there are native solutions I'd also like to check them as long as I can implemenet them into my HTML mock-up.

EDIT: A more simply question: Is it possible to implement a check for each pixel the canvas API should draw to abort drawing the pixel if it doesn't fit some conditions? I don't think that the chance is high that the question becomes affirmed but its really woth it.

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do (what is your application is about), if you have some code share it.

Comment: It shall display OGRE .mesh Models. And I would like to do so by using the canvas API and javascript.

Comment: are you looking for game engine on Java script & canvas?

Comment: Unless you are an 3D expert, I would highly recommend you to use an external engine like away3d or alternativa for this. Both supply GPU support and have import filters for many 3D model formats. Rendering 3D can become a very nasty thing...

Comment: Dont use Adobe Air for that. It is not powerful enough.

Comment: Even it may become a bit nasty I'll like to write it on my own. So far the programm as it is can display the models in wireframe mode. I'm pretty far with the solid rendering but I have to write a z-buffer.

Comment: @PaulFacklam you said AIR isn't powerfull enough. But why do Mozilla and Chrome are able to draw complex 3d modell quite easily for examply with three.js? I don't get the difference there.

Comment: @user2953241 Because Adobe Air is not a standalone browser written in c++. An example: Create a simple Air projekt where you display a div  with shadows (CSS3) and move it via JavaScript from the left to the right and back. You will see it slows down dramatically. May be this article helps you finding out if Air is the right framework for your needs: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_performance.html

Comment: So using Flash with the Molehill/Stage 3D acceleration in AIR wouldn't fix the performance neither?